# Migrating jdk 8 to jdk 11, mysql throwing error for SSL

Tags: java, mysql

The mysql connector version is 5.1.42 and the connector string in ds.properties.j2 is:

```
ds.datasource.name=coreDS
ds.datasource.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
ds.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://{{ core_db_host }}:{{ core_db_port }}/{{ core_db_schema }}?useSSl=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false
ds.datasource.username={{ core_db_user }}
ds.datasource.password={{ core_db_password }}
```

Getting below Error:

```
> TASK [jetty : Jetty | Report errors in
> /opt/jetty/base/default/logs/error.log]
> **************************************************** ok: [localhost] => {
>     "msg": "ERRORS found in /opt/jetty/base/default/logs/error.log: 2020-07-17 11:54:44,652 ERROR [com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool]
> (main) coreDS - Exception during pool initialization.\n2020-07-17
> 11:54:44,659 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader]
> (main) Context initialization failed" } Caused by:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol
> is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

Comment: 1. Use `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to get more details, specifically which TLS versions are supported by your client.
2. Verify which TLS versions your MySQL supports on server's side: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_tls_version
3. Configure both sides to match common TLS version. More here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-using-ssl.html

Answer (score 1):

If your connection is genuinely exposed to the network or you are working in a production environment with real data, then sure: we shouldn't be disabling SSL by including the option useSSL=false.

Try to update the JDBC connection string to include the latest protocol version as foloowing:
`jdbc:mysql://<hostName>:<portNumber>/<schemaName>?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2`

We have to explicitly mention the type of TLS protocol while establishing the DB connection in JDK 11.